# redux-form custom dynamic validation inside FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, validation, redux-form

I am trying to solve validation of two fields. It is two multiselects, where I need to have the same count of selected items in both fields.

I have tried to follow this example: https://redux-form.com/6.6.2/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/ But problem is that I am using FieldArray to dynamically add new rows.

I tried to make a function like this

```
const validateCount = (member) => (values, allValues) => {
  // validation funciton
}
```

`member` is an identifier for row in FieldArray.

But when I am calling this function in the render cycle, there is an infinite loop.

```
<FieldArray component={this.renderMapping} name="mapping" />
```

...

```
renderMapping = ({fields}) => {
  ...
    {fields.map((member, index) => {
      <Field
        component={MultiSelectField}
        name={`${member}.select1`}
        validate={required}
        ...
      />
      <Field
        component={MultiSelectField}
        name={`${member}.select2`}
        validate={[required, validateCount(member)]} // <<<<<<<< THIS IS PROBLEM
        ...
      />
    }
  ...
}
```

please, any ideas how to solve it?

It is in console.log, it is probably calling infinite render

```
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:44.900
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:44.934
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:44.962
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:44.977
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.018
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.044
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.061
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.099
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.147
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.163
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.192
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.225
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.234
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.265
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.301
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.313
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.356
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.395
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.407
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS @ 13:25:45.445
redux-logger.js:1  action @@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD @ 13:25:45.483
```

Comment: Why are you writing it this way: ``name={`${member}.select1`}``? Can't you just use `name={member.select1}`?

Comment: because member is mapping[0], mapping[1] ... etc (it is inside array.map() )

Comment: I see that, but you don't need this syntax. There is no problem with using the variable in the arrow function as usual.

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: Cleaned my comment as per the update.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, which is not the best but only one working.

in `componentDidMount` and in `componentWillUpdate` I am calling generator of validation functions which I have created.

```
generateValidationFunctions = props => {
  const { values } = props;

  const size = get(values, 'mapping.length', 0);

  if (this.validationFunctions.length < size) {
    for (let i = this.validationFunctions.length; i < size; i++) {
      this.validationFunctions.push(this.validateCount(`mapping[${i}]`));
    }
  }
}
```